# Уменьшить размер apk с Yandex mapkit

Tags: android, gradle, yandexmapkit

Использую в приложении Yandex mapkit

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.0.0-lite'
```

При сборке размер apk увеличился с 17Мб до 117Мб. С разработчиками связался, пока молчат. на GitHub нашёл их ответ:

```
Начиная с версии 3.1 мы разбили mapkit на части, которые можно подключать по отдельности. Теперь можно убрать directions, search, places и masstransit из build.gradle, если их функциональность не используется. Если получится убрать их все, размер должен уменьшиться раза в два.
```

Как можно убрать directions, search, places и masstransit из build.gradle?

Comment: Вы уже используете lite версию. Размер такой большой потому что в apk хранятся версии библиотеки для разных abi. При публикации через market используйте aab вместо apk и гугл будет удалять лишние версии в зависимости от телефона польозвателя

Comment: Возможно и так. Понаблюдаем

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае появился похожий кейс, когда подняли `minSDK` с 21 до 24.

Мне помогло уменьшить размер apk почти в 2 раза добавление вот этого кода в `gradle`:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
}
```

подробнее об этом - в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/JniLibsPackagingOptions#uselegacypackaging).

другой вариант - добавить эту строчку в `Manifest.xml`:

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

подробнее об этом почитать можно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440105/apk-size-increased-35mb-when-bumping-min-sdk-from-21-to-24/63417612#63417612) и вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs).

Но нужно иметь ввиду, что это уменьшит размер apk, но увеличится размер уже установленного приложения.
Как сказано в документации, если вы выкладываете на Google Play свой несжатый apk, то консоль его сожмет еще лучше, и размер установленного приложения будет меньше, чем если выложить сжатый apk описанным выше способом.

Если есть возможность, то лучше использовать aab, вместо apk.

Comment: Тут палка о двух концах - вы уменьшили размер APK, но приложение займёт больше места в памяти устройства после установки и для пользователя это более критично, хотя и размер APK может отпугнуть ещё до загрузки.

Comment: @woesss да, Вы правы, спасибо, что напомнили. Добавил эту информацию в ответе